# Passing variables with include in salt-stack

Tags: salt-stack

I have several states that are almost the same. All of them deploy project, create virtualenv and configure supervisor. Difference is only in repo, project name and some additional actions.

A lot of code is duplicated. Is it possible to put the same parts into file and include it with additional variables?

In Ansible it can be done this way:

```
tasks:
  - include: wordpress.yml
    vars:
        wp_user: timmy
        ssh_keys:
          - keys/one.txt
          - keys/two.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question looks similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37946983/saltstack-how-do-i-repeat-other-states-with-context/37960984#37960984)

If I understood your question correctly - I believe the best way to achieve what you want is to use [Salt Macros](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/2015.8/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.jinja.html#macros).

With this most of your state will go to macros with placeholders being parameters like:

```
# lib.sls
{% macro create_user(user, password) %}
{{user}}:
  user.present:
    - home: /home/{{user}}
    - password: {{password}}
{% endmacro %}
```

Then your state will look like:

```
# john.sls
{% from 'lib.sls' import create_user with context %}
{{ create_user('john', '<password hash>') }}
```

and:

```
# jane.sls
{% from 'lib.sls' import create_user with context %}
{{ create_user('john', '<password hash>') }}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I found out there is another way to archive it without messing with templates (more Ansible way). Create an abstract state "python-project". Create concrete roles then and provide different pillars to these roles:

**salt/top.sls:**

```
base:
  'roles:python-project-1':
    - match: grain
    - python-project

  'roles:python-project-2':
    - match: grain
    - python-project
```

**pillar/top.sls:**

```
base:
  'roles:python-project-1':
    - match: grain
    - common-pillars
    - pillars-for-the-first

  'roles:python-project-2':
    - match: grain
    - common-pillars
    - pillars-for-the-second
```

Structure:

```
pillar/top.sls
pillar/common-pillars/init.sls
pillar/pillars-for-the-first/init.sls
pillar/pillars-for-the-second/init.sls
salt/top.sls
salt/python-project/init.sls
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jinja imports to do that:

**top.sls**

```
{% set user = 'john' %}
{% include 'config.sls' %}
```

**config.sls**

```
file.managed:
  - name: '/Users/{{ user }}/.config
  - user: {{ user }}
```